# Merging non-contiguous polygons in OpenLayers 3 / Turf.js

Tags: openlayers, merge, turf

I need to merge polygons that are in close vicinity to each other.

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

I want the user to select both polygons and then merge them when clicking on a button, so something like this is returned (the area in between would be filled and all of it would be one large polygon):

[image]

My initial idea was to use Turf.js to generate hulls, but this is obviously not giving me what I want.

A convex hull returns way too much:

[image]

And a convex hull returns way too little:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve my goal in OpenLayers 3, natively, or with the assistance of Turf.js? (I am open to other libraries as well)

Comment: Did you end up coming up with a solution? I'm about to implement exactly the same requirement :)

Comment: I ended up letting the user digitize the area in between and then used the 3 polygons to merge them... it's the only way every user gets what they want :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me. Our requirement needs it to happen automagically, but it's that magic I'm struggling with. Cheers.

Comment: I really do not think there are any universal ways to solve this automatically. It is a much more complex problem than it seems at first. I wish you good luck and if you come up with something, feel free to share it, I'd be happy to upvote :-)